# Why the svn local working copy still download the directory which has no access right

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

Environment:VisualSVN + TortoiseSVN

There is a directory named A in SVN repository “Code”. User James can read directory A, James create a local working copy named “OldJamesWC” and checkout the “Code”.

Then the SVN admin remove access rule of directory A for James(set “no access” of A for James).

Now James can’t see A when he using “browse repository” function of TortoiseSVN.

But the “OldJamesWC” working copy still keep connection with directory A, if James do “svn update”, the working copy will download the contents of directory A, even delete directory A of working copy. Why?

Until now, the only solution I found is creating a new working copy and checkout, the directory A will not appear in the new working copy.

Answer (score 0):

> But the “OldJamesWC” working copy still keep connection with directory
>   A, if James do “svn update”, the working copy will download the
>   contents of directory A, even delete directory A of working copy. Why?

It simply restores the data from the pristine store which is already in the working copy's `.svn` directory just because there was Read access at the time when you made the checkout.